# Python (Redmine integration) causes massive memory leaks - no idea why/

Tags: python, discord.py, redmine

I am creating a discord bot, that uses asynchronous functions to check if something changed in a list of tuples. **issues_set** contains individual issues, in which there are tuples such as id: 5, money: 1000 etc...

This piece of code creates a huge memory leak. Can anyone tell me why?

bot login:

```
redmine = Redmine(URL, key=KEY)

async def loopThroughIssues(issues_set):
    project = redmine.issue.all()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if (len(issues_set) < len(project)):
        await send_new_object_message(project[0])
    elif (len(issues_set) == len(project)):
        for issues in issues_set:
            current_issue = project.get(issues.id)
            try:
                new_tuple = returnNotMatches(issues, current_issue)
            except:
                continue
            new_tuple = [[i for i in sub if i[0] != 'spent_hours'] for sub in new_tuple]
            new_tuple = [[i for i in sub if i[0] != 'total_spent_hours'] for sub in new_tuple]
            new_tuple = [[i for i in sub if i[0] != 'total_estimated_hours'] for sub in new_tuple]
            new_tuple = [[i for i in sub if i[0] != 'updated_on'] for sub in new_tuple]
            if (new_tuple[0] != new_tuple[1]):
                print('found a change')
    objgraph.show_most_common_types()
    await loopThroughIssues(redmine.issue.all())
```

imports:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import platform
import subprocess
import objgraph
from discord.ext import commands
from redminelib import Redmine
from redminelib.exceptions import AuthError
```

returnNotMatches:

```
def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    return [[x for x in a if x not in b], [x for x in b if x not in a]]
```

Thanks for all help in advance!!

Comment: There are a lot of undefined variables here. Please provide a [mcve]. By memory leak, you mean that there is unfreed memory that your program no longer uses?  How are you measuring this?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh hi, I added more code to it hope it helps.

Using the objgraph shows that the dict type always goes by 500 every time it loops, I have no clue what the problem is.